# How to solve this quadratic recursion?

Tags: calculus

I attempt to solve the following recursive relation: $\zeta_1$ is known, and
$$\zeta_n= \sum_{j=1}^{n-1} \zeta_j \zeta_{n-j}, n\ge 2.$$
I compute out the first six terms of the sequence $\{\zeta_j\}_{j\in \mathbb{N}}$:
$$\zeta_1, \zeta_1^2 , 2\zeta^3, 5\zeta^4 ,14\zeta^5, 42\zeta^6,\dots $$
But I want to derive out the general term formula for $\{\zeta_j\}_{j\in \mathbb{N}}$. According to the paper I'm reading, $\{\zeta_j\}$ is equal to the sequence of coefficients of the Taylor expansion of $f$ given by
$$f(z)=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4\zeta_1 z} }{2}.$$
around $z=0$, which is precisely $$\frac{(2n-3)!!2^{n-1}}{n!}\zeta_1^n $$ by the calculation. It seems perfectly fit to the terms I get. My question is:

1. How can the author find the sequence is exactly the coefficients of $f$?
2. Does $\zeta_n$ follow the domination: $\exists C>0, \zeta_n \le C^n$?

Comment: Pretty close to the [Catalan numbers recurrence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number) relationship.

Comment: See for example https://oeis.org/A000108 where you will find your coefficients 1, 1, 2, 5, 14, 42, etc.

Comment: @JeanMarie Yes, it is exactly what I want to find!

Comment: @JeanMarie wanted:)